# successive row-wise modification of a column using mutate from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to modify individual items within a column successively using dplyr::mutate. I can do it by using mutate several times, such as follows.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
mutate( . , a = ifelse( a == 1, 'one', a) ) %>%
mutate( . , a = ifelse( b == 2, 'two', a) )
```

This gives the result I expected.

However, what I'm wondering is why the same cannot be done with this, failing to modify 2 to 'two':

```
df2 <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
    mutate( . , 
    a = ifelse( a == 1, 'one', a),
    a = ifelse( a == 2, 'two', a)
 )
```

It seems I do not fully understand how mutate works, and just want a better understanding of it. Thanks.

Comment: It works for me. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

actually I think it is getting confused with mutate from plyr, which was also loaded. if I specify dplyr::mutate, it works.

```
df2 <- data.frame( a = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate( . , 
        a = ifelse( a == 1, 'one', a),
        a = ifelse( a == 2, 'two', a)
     )
```